# Like button: stopped working on 1 page only (has over 600 likes) - returns error if pressed

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

simple problem: Like button on one (and only one) of my pages has stopped working. the page is

http://www.tribalmixes.com/browse.php and it has over 600 likes

(as reported by https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.tribalmixes.com/browse.php)

this has been for a week or two. a few weeks ago my main page Like button was doing that same thing, - returning error if pressed, but it somehow fixed itself. now this second biggest page is doing it.. i tried working it via standard facebook button, or via addthis rendered button - nothing.. all other pages are fine. and i have over 20k pages where one can press a like button.. lint shows no errors...

all pages are generated with OGP, fb app id and admin id included, all pages have same headers, well, the technical part is same, titles and all are different, of course..

please, help! 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just tried it, works perfectly fine and shows up on facebook too. also the OG tags are perfect. i would say it´s just a temporary facebook problem that you cannot fix. different facebook accounts usually show different behaviour. also, it could be a problem of your network/internet...